# ClassNotFoundException: Using custom java rule for PMD ruleset

Tags: java, maven, classpath, classnotfoundexception, pmd

I have added a custom PMD rule using official documentation (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/howtowritearule.html)

Rule:

```
package com.comp.www.lty.awards.service.pmd;

import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.*;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.*;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.*;

public class WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule extends AbstractJavaRule {
    public Object visit(ASTWhileStatement node, Object data) {
        Node firstStmt = node.jjtGetChild(1);
        if (!hasBlockAsFirstChild(firstStmt)) {
            addViolation(data, node);
        }
        return super.visit(node,data);
    }
    private boolean hasBlockAsFirstChild(Node node) {
        return (node.jjtGetNumChildren() != 0 && (node.jjtGetChild(0) instanceof ASTBlock));
    }
}
```

This is my ruleset xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My custom rules"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>While loop desc</description>
    <rule name="WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule"
          message="Avoid using 'while' statements without curly braces"
          class="com.comp.www.lty.awards.service.pmd.WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule">
        <description>
            Avoid using 'while' statements without using curly braces
        </description>
        <priority>3</priority>

        <example>
            <![CDATA[
    public void doSomething() {
      while (true)
          x++;
    }
]]>
        </example>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

I am using mvn to run these pmd rules. Works fine when I try to use existing rules from pmd jar, but whenever I try to use my above custom rule, I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.comp.www.lty.awards.service.pmd.WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseSingleRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:377)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:291)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:242)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:176)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:171)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:331)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:289)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:242)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:176)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:171)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSets(RuleSetFactory.java:135)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSets(RuleSetFactory.java:119)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RulesetsFactoryUtils.getRuleSets(RulesetsFactoryUtils.java:31)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.AbstractPMDProcessor.createRuleSets(AbstractPMDProcessor.java:54)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.MultiThreadProcessor.processFiles(MultiThreadProcessor.java:38)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD.processFiles(PMD.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executePmd(PmdReport.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executePmdWithClassloader(PmdReport.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.canGenerateReport(PmdReport.java:254)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Although not an ideal solution, but even I spent time to include this custom rule class file in the pmd jar ([Custom Java PMD rule: Can't find the class CustomRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639817/custom-java-pmd-rule-cant-find-the-class-customrule)), but that didn't help either.

pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.4.0.RELEASE
    
    lty-awards-service
    com.comp.www
    war
    lty-awards-service
    Spring Boot Service Sample
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        1.8

```
    <findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.3</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>
    <findbugs.include.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/include.xml</findbugs.include.filter.location>
    <findbugs.exclude.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/exclude.xml</findbugs.exclude.filter.location>
    <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.5</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
    <pmd.version>5.3.2</pmd.version>
    <pmdRule.version>5.1.0</pmdRule.version>
    <pmd.ruleset.location>buildtools/pmd-rules/ltyawardsservicepmd.xml</pmd.ruleset.location>
    <pmd.skip>false</pmd.skip>
    <pmd.typeResolution>true</pmd.typeResolution>

    <!-- spring boot -->
    <debug.port>5000</debug.port>
    <run.jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dapplication.home=. -Dapplication.name=${project.name}
        -Dapplication.environment=dev -Dproject.name=${project.name} -Xdebug
        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debug.port}
    </run.jvmArguments>

    <error-inspector.version>0.1.9</error-inspector.version>
    <platform-diagnostics.version>0.0.43</platform-diagnostics.version>

</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
        <version>${pmdRule.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/Users/babu/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd/5.1.0/test.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.comp.prime.errorcatalog</groupId>
                                <artifactId>error-inspector</artifactId>
                                <version>${error-inspector.version}</version>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/error-inspect</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>inspect.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.comp.www.platform</groupId>
                                <artifactId>platform-diagnostics-main</artifactId>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/error-inspect/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>platform-diagnostics-main.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <message>.*** ERROR: Detected Maven version ${maven.version}, We need Maven 3.0.3 or
                                    higher ***.
                                </message>
                                <version>[3.0.3,)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <message>.*** ERROR: Detected JDK version ${java.version}, We need JDK
                                    ${project.jdk.version} or higher ***.
                                </message>
                                <version>${project.jdk.version}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-dont-exist</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireFilesDontExist>
                                <files>
                                    <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/scala</file>
                                </files>
                            </requireFilesDontExist>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${project.jdk.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaCompatVersion>${scala.major.minor.version}</scalaCompatVersion>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms512m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx2048m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd.ruleset</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>/Users/babu/Downloads/cache.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.comp.www.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>platform-build-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${platform-build-tools.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>${project.jdk.version}</targetJdk>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <skip>${pmd.skip}</skip>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${pmd.ruleset.location}</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cpd-report</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        <goal>pmd</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
<!--<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>-->
```

```
Here test.jar is my jar bundled (i.e. pmd jar unbundled, added class file & ruleset and again bundled it as test.jar). Although this is not how I want to use the rule. But if there is a better way to use pmd jar as it is & add a mvn dependency for new rule that is the ideal solution I'm looking for. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your custom rule jar to the classpath when PMD runs. You should bundle your custom PMD rule in its own Maven dependency, then you can include it in the PMD plugin classpath by adding a dependency to your plugin configuration like so:

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
              <artifactId>my-custom-pmd-rule</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          ...
        </plugin>
```

See [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) for more information about plugin classloading. See how it says:

> Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the dependencies of the current project nor its **build output**

Try changing your pom.xml file to the following. Notice I moved your test.jar dependency to the plugin dependencies so that it'll be loaded on the plugin's classpath. Note that you don't have to bundle your rules with PMD. You just need to package your rules in its own jar and include it in the plugin dependencies section.

```
<findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.3</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>

    <findbugs.include.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/include.xml</findbugs.include.filter.location>
    <findbugs.exclude.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/exclude.xml</findbugs.exclude.filter.location>
    <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.5</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
    <pmd.version>5.3.2</pmd.version>
    <pmdRule.version>5.1.0</pmdRule.version>
    <pmd.ruleset.location>buildtools/pmd-rules/ltyawardsservicepmd.xml</pmd.ruleset.location>
    <pmd.skip>false</pmd.skip>
    <pmd.typeResolution>true</pmd.typeResolution>

    <!-- spring boot -->
    <debug.port>5000</debug.port>
    <run.jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dapplication.home=. -Dapplication.name=${project.name}
        -Dapplication.environment=dev -Dproject.name=${project.name} -Xdebug
        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debug.port}
    </run.jvmArguments>

    <error-inspector.version>0.1.9</error-inspector.version>
    <platform-diagnostics.version>0.0.43</platform-diagnostics.version>

</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.comp.prime.errorcatalog</groupId>
                                <artifactId>error-inspector</artifactId>
                                <version>${error-inspector.version}</version>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/error-inspect</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>inspect.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.comp.www.platform</groupId>
                                <artifactId>platform-diagnostics-main</artifactId>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/error-inspect/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>platform-diagnostics-main.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <message>.*** ERROR: Detected Maven version ${maven.version}, We need Maven 3.0.3 or
                                    higher ***.
                                </message>
                                <version>[3.0.3,)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <message>.*** ERROR: Detected JDK version ${java.version}, We need JDK
                                    ${project.jdk.version} or higher ***.
                                </message>
                                <version>${project.jdk.version}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-dont-exist</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireFilesDontExist>
                                <files>
                                    <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/scala</file>
                                </files>
                            </requireFilesDontExist>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${project.jdk.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaCompatVersion>${scala.major.minor.version}</scalaCompatVersion>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms512m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx2048m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd.ruleset</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <scope>system</scope><systemPath>/Users/babu/Downloads/cache.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.comp.www.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>platform-build-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${platform-build-tools.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmdRule.version}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>

  <systemPath>/Users/babu/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd/5.1.0/test.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>${project.jdk.version}</targetJdk>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <skip>${pmd.skip}</skip>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${pmd.ruleset.location}</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cpd-report</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        <goal>pmd</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
<!--<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>-->
```

Comment: In my case, I tried bundling the custom rule class to existing pmd jar & that jar dependency is included in my pom.xml (since I'm able to run other rules from the same jar). When I unbundle the jar, the custom rule class file is present but it is not being picked up during the build. Yes, I did mvn clean too.

Comment: Are you running PMD as a maven plugin? If so, the custom rule class + PMD jar that you've bundled together needs to be in the plugin's dependencies (as shown in my snippet), not your project dependencies. It would be helpful to see the relevant parts of your pom.xml

Comment: Yes, I'm using maven plugin for the PMD. Here is the snippet of plugin I'm using:

Comment: <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
       <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.comp.www.lty.awards.service.pmd</groupId>
      <artifactId>WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: I can't tell which section of the pom.xml that came from. Can you edit your answer and give the entire pom.xml?

Comment: I edited the question and added pom.xml too. Thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: How to do this in gradle build